# Get textbox elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, textbox

I need to loop through all textboxes on a page and gather their IDs so that I can have backward compatibility placeholder text in IE7.

Here is my code:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
placeHolder(boxes[i].id);
}
```

This works perfectly, but it also selects my submit button which I don't want.

The only thing my textboxes have in common is `type="text"`. So is there anyway of getting just elements that are of the text type within Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if(boxes[i].type == "text") placeHolder(boxes[i].id);
}
```

Comment: For the OP, given the above, consider storing a reference to the element so you don't have to use *getElementById* later.